# IntelliJ IDEA/Pycharm - how to make the font smoother

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, fonts, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 2017.2.1 on Ubuntu Mate with inconsulata font. 
Until today It looked like this and I loved it:

[image]

Today it changed for no reason at all and it look like this:
[image]

As you can see is more "thin" and I hate it.

The anti aliasing is configured:
[image]

And in the file `pycharm64.vmoptions` the `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings` setting is  on `on`

I did not change other settings in Pycharm or Ubuntu.
How can I make the font more "fat" and smooth like in the first image?

Pycharm, JRE and JVM version:

```
PyCharm 2017.2.1
Build #PY-172.3544.46, built on August 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12 i386
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
```

This is how the power saving settings are:[image][image][image]

Comment: What has changed in IDE: the version, any settings? What [IDE boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) is used, have you changed it?

Comment: I did not change any setting or version. The jdk used is OpenJDK server VM by Oracle and it's still the same as before.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you changed a theme to dark or updated, it seems like a bug in the IDE.

Try restarting, changing the font, and make sure "Power Save Mode" is turned off.

Comment: I did not change the theme o update Pycharm I tried to restart and change the font several times, no effect. I updated the question to show the "Power Save Mode" windows.